# Dynamic query to perform SOQL action not working

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I'm trying to make a dynamic soql query with few parameters, but have not been able to execute it properly

```
string knowledgeQuery = '';
string publishStatusOnline = 'Online';
// At the moment 'Knowledge__kav' only supports two languages 'is-is' and 'en-us'
if(language == 'is-is'){
    language = 'is';
    knowledgeQuery = 'SELECT Id, Customer_Facing_Instruction__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE UrlName = :name AND PublishStatus = :publishStatusOnline AND language = :language ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1';
} else {
    knowledgeQuery = 'SELECT Id, Customer_Facing_Instruction__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE UrlName = :name AND PublishStatus = :publishStatusOnline ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1';
}

System.debug(knowledgeQuery);
Knowledge__kav article = Database.query(knowledgeQuery);
        
return article;
```

Tke knowledgeQuery string looks like this `SELECT Id, Customer_Facing_Instruction__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE UrlName = :name AND PublishStatus = :publishStatusOnline ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: What's the result? 0 rows? Exception thrown? Don't you have to cast it? `Knowledge__kav article = ((List<Knowledge__kav>) Database.query(knowledgeQuery))[0];`

Answer (score 1):

After checking the code, because there is really nothing dynamic, I was wondering the need for the dynamic query. I guess you could achieve basically the same by doing:

```
Knowledge__kav article;
String publishStatusOnline = 'Online';
// At the moment 'Knowledge__kav' only supports two languages 'is-is' and 'en-us'
if(language == 'is-is'){
    language = 'is';
    article = [SELECT Id, Customer_Facing_Instruction__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE UrlName = :name AND PublishStatus = :publishStatusOnline AND language = :language ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1];
} else {
    article = [SELECT Id, Customer_Facing_Instruction__c FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE UrlName = :name AND PublishStatus = :publishStatusOnline ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1];
}
        
return article;
```

Comment: There's some stupidity in the Knowledge Base (it's a different product SF purchased ages ago and it still shows, like only there you can use data categories, "update viewstat" etc weirdness. It's part of general SOQL spec but applicable only to KB, goes to different database). You can't bind variables in compiled queries. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soql_sosl_intro.htm

Comment: Oh I see, really good to know! Thank you.
Still, the use of the bind variables here can be easily bypassed so the approach could still be used I think.